# Links to Excel files are opening differently for different users

Tags: excel, browser, ms-office

I have a link to an Excel file that opens in Excel Online. When opening it, some users are getting prompted to open the file in Excel 2016 and some users are getting prompted to open with 'Url:Excel Protocol. Due to network restrictions, all users who are prompted to open with 'Url:Excel Protocol' are not able to open the document. I need everyone to be prompted to open in Excel 2016. Any way to make this consistent for all users? I appreciate any ideas! Thanks!

Here is how my link is formatted: /sites/TEAMSite/TEST%20Documents/TEST_742/FY18%20TEST%20Doc%20TEST%20Rev2.xlsm?Web=1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Users getting the first error do not have Excel installed locally, so the attempt is to route them to a web-based Excel app (Office365-Excel) ? The second user does have a local Excel/Office installation?

Comment: Supplementary to Peter's cmment ... If excel is installed the file associates aren't pointing to Excel locally

Comment: @LinkOps -  Thanks so much for the replies. Yes both users do have Excel installed locally. If the files associates aren't pointing to Excel locally, is that something that can be changed by the user. Or would that be a system admin? Apologies for my ignorance, just not sure how to resolve for all involved. Thanks again, its much appreciated!

Comment: Loady toad, Depends on how locked down your environment is. If it's a global requirement then you could possibly make a group policy to change it on all users in an AD OU or member of a security group.